# List<class> Method exposing WCF service in MVC 4

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC 4 and WCF Class Library I had added method that is return List and I have added reference of WCF services.
now I am creating proxy of ServiceReference1 then I am not able to get this ServiceReference1 object.
if I changed return type to string then it working..

I had tried changing all collection type but I dint get ServiceReference1 object.!

where I am wrong or what is the solution.?

My WCF code is here

```
public class BuildTrackerService : IBuildTrackerService
{
    public List<Property> DoWork()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Property> objProperty = new List<Property>();
        SqlConnection conn = DbConnection.GetConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("[GetPropertyDetail]", conn);
        adpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            adpt.Dispose();
        }
        objProperty = DataTableHelper.ConvertTo<Property>(dt);
        return objProperty;
    }
}
```

MY MVC 4 ActionResult is like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

    /*
        ==> this ServiceReference1 is not accessible here....!
        var obj = new ServiceReference1.BuildTrackerServiceClient();
    */

    var objct = obj.DoWork();
    return View();
}
```

I had tried with !

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you please provide little more details. Because i have tried in my solution and it is not giving me such error or issue. So please if you can post code, which will help me to rectify it.

Comment: I had modify with description please have a look...!

Answer (score 0):

With a WCF web service you can transport only primitive types. Changes your list to an array and try it again.